# Updating Commit Message in Mercurial MQ extension

Tags: version-control, mercurial, mercurial-queue

After using `hg qnew` and `hg qrefresh` to create and update a patch that I want to apply to my repository, but the commit message that I wrote when I did `hg qnew` was not very good, it did not reference the ticket number from trac, and I would like to say something in it about some of the issues that my commit addresses.

How do I do something like `hg qrewritemycommitmessage`. I have examined the [docs on the website](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/MqExtension) and I have come up blank.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just do `hg qrefresh -m "new commit message"`.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to

```
$ hg qrefresh -m "new message"
```

suggested by kuy, you can also use

```
$ hg qrefresh -e
```

to edit the *current* message. I find that very handy since I often have multi-line commit messages that I need to revise many times over the lifetime of a patch. Infact, I always create my patches with no commit message — just `hg qnew foo` — and then edit the commit message as I go along.

Comment: +1 - way more useful, since you don't necessarily know exactly what to write until the code change has been implemented.